# Alert View Click not calling instantly like iOS 6 in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, ios7

In my application while user go to the next view controller I am showing indicator with cancel button. On cancel button click i m setting value -2 for one variable like `appDel.Val = -2;` And before push to next controller i m checking that if `appDel.Val = -2;` then return. So no need further process.

this is working fine with iOS6 devices. When user tap on cancel in `UIAlertView` Delegate method for Alert click calls immediately and value set for appDel.Val=-2. So it will return without any further process.

Bit With iOS7 it creating issue like when user tap on cancel in alert, alertview delegate method is calling after completing current process for push view controller. So `appDel.Val=-2` will be set after push controller from alert click method as alert delegate method is not calling immediately same like iOS 6

Can any one please suggest, How can i fix this for iOS 7?

**Here is my code.**

```
-(void)goToNextViewController:(NSDictionary*)outputDictionary
{
    myViewController *mtvc=[appDel.myDict valueForKey:[outputDictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];
    if (mtvc) {
        [appDel showindicator:@"Please Wait..."];
    }else{
        [appDel showindicator:@"Connecting..."];
    }

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    self.rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:outputDictionary];
    appDel.activeId = [outputDictionary valueForKey:@"id"];

    if(!mtvc)
    {
        myViewController *mtvc = [[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];
        appDel.tempViewController=mtvc;
        appDel.tempViewController.isVeryFirst = YES;
        [mtvc release];
    }
    else
    {
        appDel.tempViewController=mtvc;
        appDel.tempViewController.isVeryFirst = NO;
        @try {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController: mtvc animated: YES];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        }

        [appDel performDismiss];
        return;
    }

    if (appDel.Val==-2)
    {
        [appDel.newConnections removeObjectForKey:appDel.activeId];
        appDel.tempViewController.isNewConnection = NO;
        appDel.Val = 0;
        [appDel performDismiss];
        return;
    }

    [appDel.newConnections setObject:appDel.tempViewController forKey:[outputDictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: appDel.tempViewController animated: YES];

    [appDel performDismiss];

}
```

**Alert click**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(alert.tag==654)
{
    self.Val = -2;
    [baseAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    baseAlert=nil;
}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show the alert view code. Which delegate method are you using?

Comment: I just made an edit plz check

Comment: Did you add the other delegate methods and see when they are called? Consider also searching the Apple dev forum and raising a bug report with Apple depending on your findings.

Comment: Yes, checked willDismissWithButtonIndex called before click at index but still after completing its current process. So that's not helping.Ok.